# WSO2 : Can I assign Facebook or Google user to a specific tenant?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

My environment is **wso2 API-M + wso2 IdP + wso2 DAS**. I set SSO with those components and Facebook and Google users can log in to my environment.

My question is :

If I create 2 tenants in API-M, how should I assign Facebook or Google users to a specific tenant I created while they logging in API-M? (without auto user provision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From service provider configuration --> Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration

check "Use tenant domain in local subject identifier"

Comment: It can only assign social users in a tenant. If I have multi tenants at the same time, how should I let  social users be assigned to the tenant they should belong to automatically?